# How to swap numbers in a python list

Tags: python

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [1,2,0]
>>> a[0], a[a[0]] = a[a[0]], a[0]
>>> a
[2, 2, 1]
```

First, why was the result not `[2, 1, 0]`?

Second, what is the best practice to swap numbers in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly right side expressions are evaluated, where `a[a[0]], a[0]` evaluate to 2 and 1.

Now they are assigned to left side expressions which are evaluated after right ones, and since `a[0]` got assigned `a[a[0]]` which is 2, thus secondly assignment to `a[a[0]]` will means assigning to `a[2]`.

Thus 2 assignments occurred, one at 0th index and other at 2nd index which is the result you see.

See [here in docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) which says right side expressions are evaluated before left ones.

Comment: Em, I thought the `=` had lower precedence than `,`. Thanks for the document.

Answer (score 2):

in your line:

```
a[0], a[a[0]] = a[a[0]], a[0]
```

the expression:

```
a[a[0]], a[0]
```

will be first evaluated then the result is unpacked and assigned to  `a[0], a[a[0]]`, first `a[0]` will be equal with `2` this means that `a[a[0]]` will be the same with `a[2]`, equivalent with:

```
a[0], a[2] = a[a[0]], a[0]
```

---

you can swap by using:

```
a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Python first assigns a new value to `a[0]`. It is then this value that is used in the index for your second variable, so you end up putting a number where you don't want it. Written out, it's more like this:

```py
x = a[a[0]]  # 2
y = a[0]
a[0] = x
a[a[0]] = y  # a[2] = 1 -- Wrong index!
```

To fix it, use a temporary variable:

```py
temp = a[a[0]]
a[0], a[temp] = a[temp], a[0]
```